# Bash escaping/expanding order

Tags: bash

I'm fairly new to Bash and I'm having trouble working out what is happening to my input as it is interpreted. Specifically, when escaping occurs relative to the other expansion steps.

From what I've read, bash does the following (in order):

- brace expansion
- tilde expansion
- parameter and variable expansion
- command substitution
- arithmetic expansion
- word splitting
- filename expansion

But this list doesn't include when it converts all escape sequences e.g. '\\' into their meanings e.g. '\'. That is, if I want to print a backslash character. The command to run is

```
echo \\
```

not

```
echo \
```

So the syntax required for the semantics of a backslash character is two backslashes. This must be converted into a single slash representation internally.

It seems to be sometime before command substitution as I found out with a small test program.

So, my question is: When does this step take place? (or a complete list of the bash interpretation loop would be perfect)

and also, are there any other subtleties in the interpreter that are likely to catch me out? (related to knowing the complete list i guess)

Comment: "when it converts all escape sequences e.g. '\' into their meanings e.g. '\'." - I'm not sure what you're talking about. Can you give an example?

Comment: Good question. If you read https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html carefully enough, you'll find that characters can be either quoted or unquoted, and only unquoted metacharacters (sometimes entire tokens) can introduce the various expansions. E.g., "A correctly-formed brace expansion must contain unquoted opening and closing braces, and at least one unquoted comma or a valid sequence expression." Therefore, escaping comes first and determines the status of each character (sometimes token or even construct), then expansions kick in.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Ironically, the markup engine converted my double backslash (inside the first set of double quotes) into a single backslash...
I'll try and edit it to keep both now, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @4ae1e1 - Thanks. So I guess bash handles escaping as part of an initial tokenization? 
Do you know if there's an 'architecture guide' or equivalent to see exactly what's going on?

Comment: @TomRees Just read the source code...

Comment: Bash's yacc grammer, in case you're interested: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y.

Comment: @TomRees: Noooo. I meant give a concrete example where you think that escape is replaced.

Comment: @TomRees: It's important. The context is unclear. Wouldn't ask it otherwise...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Thanks, let me know if that's still unclear :)

Comment: Note: From the manual: "      The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion, parameter, variable and arithmetic expansion and command substitution (done in a left-to-right fashion), word  splitting,
       and pathname expansion."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the man page's Expansion section, just before the Redirection section.

> Quote Removal
>
> After the preceding expansions, all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and " that did not result from one of the  above  expansions
>          are removed.

Quote removal is one final process after the seven expansions you list.

Comment: Thank-you. I didn't realize this came under quote removal.

[Link to man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quote-Removal.html#Quote-Removal)

So it appears that escaping is used to distinguish between syntax recognized by the various expansions - e.g. ${var} - and those same characters 'verbatim' - e.g. \$\{var\}, which now won't be 'seen' by parameter expansion.

Comment: Escaping a character prevents the shell from applying any special behavior. Note that `\${var}` would be sufficient, since without the parameter expansion, `{` and `}` no longer have special meaning. Also, quotes are just a syntactic shortcut for escaping multiple characters. For example, the shell makes no distinction between `\$\$` and `'$$'`. They both represent the exact same string.